# Passing a variable to another class, perform a calculation then pass it back

Tags: c#

I'm trying to code a simple calculator but reading and listening to different tutorials I should follow the OOP method. Attempting to rather than having all my code in the button click method I thought the logical approach would be to have all the calculations in one form e.g. add divide, percentage and the form1 class pass the variable values to the calculation class where all the logic happens. But for some reason total always equals the number I entered last and not the sum of total + total. Any help is appreciated.

```
namespace calculator
{
    public partial class calculator : Form
    {
        public calculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
            calculations.total = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);

            calculations.GetPrice();
            displayBox.Text = Convert.ToString(calculations.total);    
        }   
    }
}
```

Calculations class

```
class Calculations
{
    public int total;

    public int GetPrice()
    {
        total =+ total;

        //See whats being stored in total
        String totalCheck = Convert.ToString(total);
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(totalCheck);                    

        return total;
    }        
}
```

Comment: You're creating a new `Calculations` class each time the button is clicked. So there's no way for the previous value to be involved. Not that it'd matter anyway because you are also setting the `total` field directly from the user input each time, which would overwrite the previous value even if you kept a single instance around. The design is not very useful anyway, but if you want to continue down this path, consider keeping a field for the running total and provide methods for the operations, where you pass in the value to be added, subtracted, divided, multiplied, etc.

Comment: Hello Peter. Could you give some more context on what exactly you want to calculate? Also, is the Calculations class you posted here complete? Because I can't see why this would even compile; You're using "calculations.totalPrice" in your calculator form, but that attribute does not exist in the posted Calculations class.

Comment: Hi this is the complete code, I was just trying to get this working before I added more button. Only thing is missing is the Using system statements. Total price should just be total.

Answer (score 2):

in GetPrice(),it should be  `total += total;` 
not `total =+ total;`.

thanks for the reminder from @Tipx.

Because of my poor English,I quote following description on *https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/index* to explain `+=` and `=+`.

> x += y – increment. Add the value of y to the value of x, store the result in x, and return the new value.
>
> +x – returns the value of x

There is no operator `=+`,`x =+ y` means `x = +y`.

Comment: To explain what @cocoa answered: += means "add total to total, and make that the new value of total". What you have, =+, is actually "total = +total", so "set total to the 'additive non-inverse' value of total".

Comment: While this answer is right about `+=`, this makes no difference and the answer will still be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a console application for this approach. Is simple to accomplish it:

```
namespace Calculations
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static List<Calculations> calcs = new List<Calculations>();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In this program you will put 10 different prices and a value will be returned.");
            Console.WriteLine();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a price: ");
                Calculations calc = new Calculations(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
                calc.GetPrice();
                calcs.Add(calc); //This is for example if you want to modify or re-access them
            }
        }
    }

    public class Calculations
    {
        private static Calculations instance;
        private static int _total;

        private static int total
        {
            get
            {
                return _total;
            }
            set
            {
                //The logic happens here.
                instance.actsubtotal = value;
                instance.acttotal = _total;
                _total += value; //The single value will be summed to a stored absolute total.
            }
        }

        //actsubtotal: Is the actual subtotal you entered.
        //acttotal: Is the total that was stored in each case, if you enter for example:
        //--- 30, 20, 50, you will have 3 instances, and the value of each acttotal will be: 30, 50, 100
        public int actsubtotal,
                   acttotal;

        public Calculations(int subtotal)
        {
            instance = this; //There is the magic, with this, you will tell the property where to find the last value.
            total = subtotal; //Pass it as a single value (without summing it) 
        }

        public void GetPrice()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("-------------");
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("You actually entered: {0}", actsubtotal);
            Console.WriteLine("Your current total is: {0}", total);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("-------------");
        }
    }
}
```

In this program you will enter a price and it will be **stored into a total**, that you will can re-access later if you want.

I don't know if this is the better way to do this, but as you can see, a value is stored into a subtotal that is later written in the console output or in your case in a MessageBox.

By this way, saving the **instance** of every call you will be **able to sum the last value you entered** by using a property.

Comment: What is the point of static fields? This is a console app but the question is about windows forms. Why do you need to track all the calculation objects?

Comment: The static property is because is a total. There aren't individual total, the total is the sum of every instance, by this reason is more logic to use a static property instead of a local one.

Comment: Do you really think you need all that code to just add numbers? This is over engineering.

Answer (score 0):

There's a better practice for doing the class but i'll follow your logic just for you not to get confused, first things first never do the messagebox show inside a class (well you can but not a good practice anyway you just used it to check the value, but practice using breakpoints):

```
public partial class calculator : Form
{
    public calculator()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
       //assuming this is clicking the Add (+) Button
    private void btnInput_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double fNum = 0.0; //initialize a variable with default value
                           //if you didn't include 0.0 you will get a "local variable" error

        Calculations calculations = new Calculations();
        calculations.Total = Convert.ToInt32(txtPrice.Text);

        fNum = calculations.GetPrice();

        //take Note the below code will really just return the value you have just entered in your textbox since you didn't used calculations.GetPrice();
        //displayBox.Text = Convert.ToString(calculations.Total);

        //the below code will show the value you have entered added
        //to itself since the logic from your class is just Total+=Total
        // example I input 1. (so Total = 1) then fNum will be (Total = 1 + 1)
        // which is 2
        displayBox.Text = Convert.ToString(fNum);


    }   
}



public class Calculations
{
    public int Total {get; set;} //Best practice to use CamelCase for properties inside a class

    public int GetPrice()
    {
        Total += Total;

        return Total;
    }        
}
```

Comment: This will yield incorrect result. All it does is that it will double the result and return it...

Comment: yes that's why I indicated it in the comment. and I also included that I followed his logic just to avoid confusion.. I don't need to spoon feed the guy.. let him do the logic I just showed what could possible go wrong in his program